# Devtools not showing content of scss files

Tags: sass, google-chrome-devtools

While surfing a website, being curious, I want to understand how some of the css is built.

So I open the devtools and inspect a specific element, on the right panels it shows me the css and a link to scss files, but I click on the name of the scss file then it seems to show me an empty file!

Any way to inspect the sass/scss files from a 3rd party website in devtools?

Comment: That's because the css file on that site includes a sourcemap, but not the original scss source files.

Comment: Thx @MiguelCalderón, do you mean that the folder and scss files that I see inside devtools are generated by Chrome from the CSS files but they are actually not sent by the server?

Comment: They are referenced by the source map, but they're not present where the source map says they are.

Answer (score 0):

You can view the original SCSS file only if the sourcemap file is included in the site's files and have been uploaded.